# What is a way to extract data from this file type?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parsing, text

I have to extract Time and coordinate (both Easting and Northing) data from a text file. I want to loop through it and populate 3 parallel arrays with all of the data contained until I reach the EOF. I have done this with XML, but this time its a bit different. Might I add that this is a SMI file that is used for CC for video files. I will post an example below:

```
<SAMI>
<HEAD>
    <STYLE TYPE="Text/css">
    <!--
        P {margin-left: 29pt; margin-right: 29pt; font-size: 24pt; text-align: center; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; color: #FF0000; background-color: #000000;}
        .SUBTTL {Name: 'Subtitles'; Lang: en-US; SAMIType: CC;}
    -->
    </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <SYNC START=0>
        <P CLASS=SUBTTL>E: 4444444 N: 4444444 Time: 13:42:07
    <SYNC START=10>
        <P CLASS=SUBTTL>E: 44444444 N: 3333330 Time: 13:42:08
    <SYNC START=1010>
        <P CLASS=SUBTTL>E: 33333333 N: 4444444 Time: 13:42:09
    <SYNC START=2010>
        <P CLASS=SUBTTL>E: 2222222 N: 3333333 Time: 13:42:10
</BODY>
</SAMI>
```

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: Currently, I was looking into doing a regex search. Not sure if that's the best way. This is a weird mix of syntaxes, kind of like cruddy HTML.

Edit- What if I was to delete everything between the '<' and '>' symbols. I might be left with a space delimited file?

Comment: As I understand it isn't a valid XML file?

Comment: No, although, it does have proper starting elements. I might be able to somehow navigate the tree and yank out all of the innertext of the <P> elements.

Comment: When I parse with XMLTextReader I am getting this exception: "System.Xml.XmlException: '0' is an unexpected token." at line 11 pos 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following pattern with .NET Regex

```
@"^(?:\s+<P CLASS=SUBTTL>E:)\s+(\d+)\s+N:\s+(\d+)\s+Time:\s+(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)"
```

The coordinates and time will be in Group[1], [2], [3]

I tested this.

```
        Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
        Match m = r.Match(input);
        if (m != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
            Debug.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
            Debug.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Blam! I had my Regex nearly working in 3 steps, but it was not nearly as concise and eloquent.

Comment: If you get some single digit hour you can use \d?\d.  What is nice about a single step is the output is part of the pattern match.   The ?: makes it a non capturing group so it does not use up Group[1].